# Cómo replicar una animación hecha en webFlow en react con next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind

Cómo están? Perdón la molestia, pero tengo una duda que me está comiendo la cabeza. Necesito replicar la animación inicial de la página [1]: https://www.ghimprove.com/mx/inicio
Los desarrolladores anteriores de la empresa utilizaron webflow y ahora me pidieron migrar la web utilizando react con next.js.
Realmente ya no se me ocurre qué librería o método utilizar para hacer ese efecto de abrir las puertas. Les agradecería si me dan una mano para orientarme, o si alguien trabajó en alguna animación similar.

Muchas gracias!!